# Angular 2 / ionic 2 read json file from local device file system

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript

I am working on an app with a special requirement - the app works offline and has "sync" mechanism.
That means that on demand, the user can sync the app with the servers.
I implemented a process that using cordova's 'FileTransfer' and node generates a json file with the most recent data, and downloads it to the local file system.
Now, I naively thought that I could just fetch the data using a stabndard htrp rquest to this file.
But It did not work. So I examined the logcat of my device and found that it is not possible to execute http requests to 'file://' protocol. While writing these lines it actualy makes sense.

Then how can I do that anyway? 
How can I fetch a file on the file system?
Is there a way to fake a service that runs on the device or somwethibf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because of different paths of json files in local browser(computer) and device (android). Create `data` folder inside the `src\assets` folder. Move your json file into that.

When we run `ionic serve`, it will move that folder (with file) into `www\assets` folder. Then do following things:

1. Import `Platform` service of `ionic2`

   ```
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
   ```

2. Inject `Platform` Service.

   ```
     constructor(private http: Http, private platform: Platform ) { }
   ```

3. Use `Platform` Service.

   ```
   public getItems() {

       var url = 'assets/data/Items.json'; 

       if (this.platform.is('cordova') && this.platform.is('android')) {
           url = "/android_asset/www/" + url;
       }

       return this.http.get(url)
           .map((res) => {
               return res.json()
           });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just use "assets/data/Items.json" instead of "/assets/data/Items.json" as file path. It will work both on browser and android device.

```
    this.http.get('assets/path/to/file').success((res) => {
       console.log(res);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out, but:

Leave out the protocol in your path, so don't use 'file://'

Instead use the path directly to where the file is stored, for example on android it will probably be '/assets/path/to/file'.
so you get:

```
this.http.get('/assets/path/to/file').success(function(response){ //do something });
```